# Running A Smart Contract With Two Nodes on Truffle

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, truffle, dapp-development

We have installed truffle to two nodes and we initialize our private blockchain with:
$geth --datadir node init genesis.json

Then we run geth on both nodes with:
$geth --datadir node --nodiscover -rpc --rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal,web3"  console

We are using same genesis.json files.

After that, we migrate contract on both nodes, and we are using:

> ContractName.deployed()
>   var contract = ContractName.at('address')

Then in the two nodes we run function like that:

> contract.then(function(cI){cI.addValue().then(function(v){console.log(v)})})

However, after a node run the contract, other node don't run on the same contract, I mean, if we want to show the values added to an array, every node shows it's own array, not a single one.

Are we running contracts in two nodes in a wrong way?

Edit: Solved the problem. We have migrated smart contract on a single node, then in all nodes, we simply created a contract instance with

> var contract = ContractName.at('address')

Answer (score 0):

As you say it works when you deploy in a node and access the contracts from other nodes using `ContractName.at(address)`.

An alternative is to copy those artifact files generated by truffle in the `build/` directory to the other nodes. The you can reference the contracts with `ContractName.deployed()`.